# Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: python, selenium

Проблема началась пару дней назад, до этого работало все нормально, выдает предупреждение: **2023-09-05 06:57:37 WARNING Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000151EDF8D1F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /session/9628239cb0e1b08440f345e130731ad**
Посмотрел в интернете этот [сайт](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547176/python-warning-retrying-retrytotal-4-connect-none-read-none-redirect-none) и этот [сайт](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7424). Сделал все что там описывается, кроме переустановки Python. Но ни чего не помогло. Может быть дело в коде, т.к. при запросе по 1 выписке, код отрабатывается без каких либо ошибок, только массово не отрабатывается (запросит 1-ну и дальше предупреждение с остановкой кода)?

Отвечаю на вопросы, которые задавали на [сайте](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7424):

> Цитата "1.Можете ли вы загрузить из PyPI с помощью curl? Нравится curl https://pypi.org/simple/flask-bcrypt/ 2. Pip пытается использовать значения из переменных окружения HTTP_PROXY и HTTPS_PROXY, они установлены? Вы можете показать вывод env | grep HTTP 3. Это в обычной домашней сети или в корпоративной среде? 4. Это всегда происходило на этом компьютере или началось недавно? 5. Если это работало в прошлом, подключены ли вы к той же сети, что и тогда? 6. Можете ли вы установить какие-либо другие пакеты?"

1. По ссылке установил Flask-Bcrypt-1.0.1.tar.gz, но проблема не решена
2. В настройках установил на "Откл." (использование прокси-сервер). это сделал по комменту из [сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547176/python-warning-retrying-retrytotal-4-connect-none-read-none-redirect-none), не знаю может быть не понял вопрос...
3. Используется корпоративная сеть на работе, перейти на обычную нет возможности.
4. и 5. Код работал только на моем компе и началось не так давно, до этого работало.
5. Какие то пакеты устанавливаются, а какие то нет, тут уже на память не вспомню какие не устанавливаются.

Все это написано в телеграмм боте aiogram. пока описывал все это, появилась идея, почему появляется предупреждение. Может быть и бред.

При вставки в чат допустим 2000 кадастровых номеров, идет проверка самих кадастровых номеров на правильность написания (функция validate_cadastre_code(code)). Возможно, что слишком часто отправляет сообщение о неправильном кадастровом номере и это как раз "забивает" телегу и блокируется. Наверно нормально объяснил...

---

```html
async def validate_cadastre_code(code):
    '''Функция которая проверяет правильность написания кадастрового номера'''
    errors = []
    cadastre_code_pattern = r"^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{7,}:"
    if not re.match(cadastre_code_pattern, code):
        errors.append("Написание кадастрового номера должно соответствовать формату: XX:XX:XXXXXXX:00, где X - цифра, где 0 - любое количество цифр\n\n")
    parts = code.split(":")
    if len(parts) < 2:
        errors.append(f'❌Ввели "{code}", а нужно ввести кадастровый номер, который содержит 3 знака ":"\n')
    if len(parts) >= 1 and (len(parts[0]) <= 1 or len(parts[0]) > 2):
        errors.append(f"❌Неверный код субъекта - {parts[0]}\n")
    if len(parts) >= 2 and (len(parts[1]) <= 1 or len(parts[1]) > 2):
        errors.append(f"❌Неверный номер района - {parts[1]}\n")
    if len(parts) >= 3 and (len(parts[2]) <= 6 or len(parts[2]) > 7):
        errors.append(f"❌Неверный код кладра, должно быть 7 цифр - {parts[2]}\n")
    if code.count(":") != 3:
        errors.append('❌Кадастровый номер обычно содержит 3 знака ":"\n')
        
    if len(errors) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        er = f'Ошибка в написании кадастрового номера - "{code}":\n\n'
        for error in errors:
            er += error
        return er

@dp.message_handler(state=bd.sear_bd)
@timeit
async def process_search_BD(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    word_to_search = message.text
    id_users_v = message.chat.id
    name_users_v = message.from_user.full_name
    message_datetime = (message.date).strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    if word_to_search.lower() in STOP_WORDS:
        await message.answer("Вы завершили поиск")
        await state.finish()
    else:
        codes = re.split(r'[-;,"\s]+', word_to_search)
        codes = [code.strip() for code in codes if code.strip() != '']
        pdf_paths = []
        for code in codes:
            is_valid = await validate_cadastre_code(code)
            if is_valid == True:
                if len(codes) < 3:
                    upload_message = await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Идет поиск...')
                    async with aiosqlite.connect(db_path) as conn:
                        async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                            await cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM archive WHERE cad_n=?", (code,))
                            result = await cursor.fetchall()
                            if len(result) == 0:
                                await cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE cad_n=? AND id=? AND date=?", (code, id_users_v, message_datetime,))
                                result = await cursor.fetchone()
                                if result is None:
                                    insert_query = f"INSERT INTO requests (cad_n, id, name, date, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                                    await cursor.execute(insert_query, (code, id_users_v, name_users_v, message_datetime, 'Запросить'))
                                    await conn.commit()
                                    await upload_message.edit_text(text=f"Поиск завершен...\n\nПо КН - {code} будет запрошена выписка позже")
                                else:
                                    await upload_message.edit_text(text=f"Сегодня уже запрашивали по КН - {code} выписку")
                            else:
                                for i in result:
                                    archive_path = i[3]
                                    await search_files_in_BD(archive_path,message)
                                    await upload_message.edit_text(text=f"Поиск завершен.")
                    
                else:
                    async with aiosqlite.connect(db_path) as conn:
                        async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                            await cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM archive WHERE cad_n= '{code}'")
                            result = await cursor.fetchall()
                            if len(result) == 0:
                                await cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE cad_n=? AND id=? AND date=?", (code, id_users_v, message_datetime,))
                                result = await cursor.fetchone()
                                if result is None:
                                    insert_query = f"INSERT INTO requests (cad_n, id, name, date, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                                    await cursor.execute(insert_query, (code, id_users_v, name_users_v, message_datetime, 'Запросить'))
                                    await conn.commit()
                                else:
                                    await message.answer(f"Сегодня уже запрашивали по КН - {code} выписку")
                            else:
                                for i in result:
                                    archive_path = i[3]
                                    pdf_paths += await search_files_in_BD_in_archive(archive_path, destination_folder)
            else:
                await message.reply(is_valid)
        if pdf_paths:
            pdf_zip_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, 'Выписка.zip')
            with zipfile.ZipFile(pdf_zip_path, 'w') as pdf_zip:
                for pdf_file_path in pdf_paths:
                    pdf_zip.write(pdf_file_path, arcname=os.path.basename(pdf_file_path))
            with open(pdf_zip_path, "rb") as file:
                await message.answer_document(document=file)
            for pdf_file_path in pdf_paths:
                await aiofiles.os.remove(pdf_file_path)
            if os.path.exists(pdf_zip_path):
                await aiofiles.os.remove(pdf_zip_path)
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Код на запрос выписок из ЕГРН в ЛК госуслуг

---

```html
async def click_one(browser):
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.DOWN).perform()
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

async def click_no_down(browser):
    actions = ActionChains(browser) 
    actions.key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
async def wait_for_element(browser, locator, timeout: int = 10, max_attempts: int = 5):
    element = None
    attempts = 0
    while element is None and attempts < max_attempts:
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
            element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        except TimeoutException:
            attempts += 1
            time.sleep(timeout)
    return element

async def request_v(code):
'''Запрос выписок'''
try:
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    # options.add_argument("--window-position=-32000,-32000")
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_extension(browser_plug_in)
    # browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>', options=options)
    browser.get('https://lk.rosreestr.ru/eservices/request-info-from-egrn/real-estate-object-or-its-rightholder')
    (await wait_for_element(browser, (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login"]'))).send_keys(LOGIN)
    (await wait_for_element(browser, (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys(PASSWORD)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > esia-root > div > esia-login > div > div.form-container.outline-none > form > div:nth-child(4) > button'))).click()
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    # await click_no_down(browser)
    (await wait_for_element(browser, (By.CLASS_NAME, 'plain-button-inline'))).click()
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="personal-cabinet-root"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]'))).click()
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="applicantCategory"]'))).send_keys('Органы государственной статистики')
    await click_one(browser)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rorganizationOrGovernmentArray[0].regDate"]'))).send_keys('09.11.2015')
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentType"]'))).send_keys('Доверенность')
    await click_one(browser)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentNumber"]'))).send_keys('Сл-326219160/23')
    # browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentNumber"]').send_keys('Сл-326219160/23')
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentIssueDate"]'))).send_keys('22.03.2023')
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.issuingAuthority"]'))).send_keys('Министерство имущественных и земельных отношений нижегородской области')
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#userAuthorityConfirmationDocument\.file'))).send_keys(filePath)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#userAuthorityConfirmationDocument\.signature'))).send_keys(filesig)
    # await asyncio.sleep(5)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#react-select-4-input'))).send_keys(code)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await click_one(browser)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-select-6-input"]'))).send_keys('Выписка из Единого государственного реестра недвижимости об объекте недвижимости')
    await click_one(browser)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="requestAboutObject.deliveryActionEmail"]'))).send_keys('shirshov@gbunoko.ru')
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="realEstateItems"]/div/div[2]/div/label/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-page-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/button'))).click()  # первая кнопка далее
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-page-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]'))).click()  # вторая кнопка далее
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CLASS_NAME, 'certificate-selector__list-option'))).click()
    (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.rros-ui-lib-button.rros-ui-lib-button--primary[data-cy="select-certificate-button"]'))).click()
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    browser.quit()
    try:
        await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="personal-cabinet-root"]/div/div[2]/div'))
        browser.quit()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    return None
except Exception as e:
    browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

При выполнении функции wait_for_element, выходит предупреждение. Т.е. код хоть и выполняется без ошибок, но все равно ищет элементы в браузере до 5 раз. Получается так, наверно...

Сам код

---

```html
async def wait_for_element(browser, locator, timeout: int = 10, max_attempts: int = 5):
    element = None
    attempts = 0
    while element is None and attempts < max_attempts:
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
            element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        except TimeoutException:
            attempts += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
    return element
    
    async def request_v(code):
    '''Запрос выписок'''
    try:
        service = Service(chromedriver_path)
        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        # options.add_argument("--window-position=-32000,-32000")
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.add_extension(browser_plug_in)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        # browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>', options=options)
        browser.get('https://lk.rosreestr.ru/eservices/request-info-from-egrn/real-estate-object-or-its-rightholder')
        (await wait_for_element(browser, (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login"]'))).send_keys(LOGIN)
        (await wait_for_element(browser, (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys(PASSWORD)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > esia-root > div > esia-login > div > div.form-container.outline-none > form > div:nth-child(4) > button'))).click()
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        # await click_no_down(browser)
        (await wait_for_element(browser, (By.CLASS_NAME, 'plain-button-inline'))).click()
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="personal-cabinet-root"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]'))).click()
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="applicantCategory"]'))).send_keys('Органы государственной статистики')
        await click_one(browser)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rorganizationOrGovernmentArray[0].regDate"]'))).send_keys('09.11.2015')
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentType"]'))).send_keys('Доверенность')
        await click_one(browser)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentNumber"]'))).send_keys('Сл-326219160/23')
        # browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentNumber"]').send_keys('Сл-326219160/23')
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.documentIssueDate"]'))).send_keys('22.03.2023')
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="userAuthorityConfirmationDocument.issuingAuthority"]'))).send_keys('Министерство имущественных и земельных отношений нижегородской области')
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#userAuthorityConfirmationDocument\.file'))).send_keys(filePath)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#userAuthorityConfirmationDocument\.signature'))).send_keys(filesig)
        # await asyncio.sleep(5)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#react-select-4-input'))).send_keys(code)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await click_one(browser)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-select-6-input"]'))).send_keys('Выписка из Единого государственного реестра недвижимости об объекте недвижимости')
        await click_one(browser)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="requestAboutObject.deliveryActionEmail"]'))).send_keys('shirshov@gbunoko.ru')
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="realEstateItems"]/div/div[2]/div/label/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-page-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/button'))).click()  # первая кнопка далее
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-page-wrapper"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]'))).click()  # вторая кнопка далее
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CLASS_NAME, 'certificate-selector__list-option'))).click()
        (await wait_for_element(browser,(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.rros-ui-lib-button.rros-ui-lib-button--primary[data-cy="select-certificate-button"]'))).click()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        browser.quit()
        try:
            await wait_for_element(browser,(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="personal-cabinet-root"]/div/div[2]/div'))
            browser.quit()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        browser.quit()
```